# How we can display ASCII code for single quote in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I got the answer but can someone please explain me how and why we need to use extra single quote????

```
Select ASCII ('''') from dual;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have to *escape* it.

- string literal begins with a single quote
- another one terminates the string ...
- ... unless it is immediately followed by another single quote which "escapes" it

For example: this is what you have:

```
SQL> Select ASCII ('''') from dual;

ASCII('''')
-----------
         39
```

If you omit one of single quotes, you'll get an invalid string:

```
SQL> Select ASCII (''') from dual;
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
```

Only two single quotes? That's OK, but - it is an empty string, not what you wanted (a single quote):

```
SQL> Select ASCII ('') from dual;

 ASCII('')
----------
```

Alternatively, instead of that many single quotes, you can use the **q-quoting mechanism** like this:

```
SQL> select ascii(q'[']') from dual;

ASCII(Q'[']')
-------------
           39

SQL>
```

Basically, you'd enclose string (that contains single quotes) into brackets. That example (with only one single quote) looks *stupid*, but - have a look at this:

```
SQL> select 'L''Oreal'   example1,
  2         q'[L'Oreal]' example2         --> this
  3  from dual;

EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
------- -------
L'Oreal L'Oreal
```

See? Within the brackets you use single quotes "normally", without escaping them. In more complex situations, that mechanism really, really helps.